# how to use Xilinx FPGA RAM?

Tags: fpga, ram

For example

```
entity xilinx_TDP_RAM is
  generic(
    ADDR_WIDTH : integer := 32;
    DATA_WIDTH : integer := 129;
    ENTRIES    : integer := 32  -- number of entries  (should be a power of 2)
    );
  port(
    clk : in std_logic;  -- clock

    addra : in std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  -- Port A Address bus, width determined from RAM_DEPTH
    addrb : in std_logic_vector(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  -- Port B Address bus, width determined from RAM_DEPTH
    dina  : in std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  -- Port A RAM input data
    dinb  : in std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  -- Port B RAM input data

    wea : in std_logic;  -- Port A Write enable
    web : in std_logic;  -- Port B Write enable
    ena : in std_logic;  -- Port A RAM Enable, for additional power savings, disable port when not in use
    enb : in std_logic;  -- Port B RAM Enable, for additional power savings, disable port when not in use

    douta : out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);  -- Port A RAM output data
    doutb : out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0)   -- Port B RAM output data
    );
end xilinx_TDP_RAM;
```

What are the relations about ADDR_WIDTH & DATA_WIDTH & ENTRIES ?
DATA_WIDTH must be 2**N ?
THX!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an xilinx interface.
but I think we can still give an answer to your question:

ADDR_WIDTH is typically be equal to:

```
ceil(log2(real(ENTRIES)))
```

without looking at the implementation,
DATA_WIDTH can be equal to anything positive (in the limit of your FPGA resources).

as a side note, the memery I used from Xilinx is xpm_memory_tdpram